# Hibernate @Lob annotation no work anymore : cannot exceed overall CLOB length with a few String?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-annotations

I have an error when I am trying to persist an Entity with a @lob String.  I remember that part of the code worked well and I don't remember changing it at all.  I am confused.  Here is what I have for an error:

> ERROR 30 04 12 23:50:31 [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] =>
>   Start position [1] cannot exceed overall CLOB length [0]
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException Cause:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
>   [life.domain_model.Post]  at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:507)
>     at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)     at
>   com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1154)
>     at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:371)  at
>   com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:193)     at
>   com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1094)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:590)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:266)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:476)
>     at
>   org.vaadin.navigator7.NavigableApplicationServlet.service(NavigableApplicationServlet.java:46)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
>   [life.domain_model.Post]  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:695)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
>     at $Proxy29.merge(Unknown Source)   at
>   life.dao.ForumDao.merge(ForumDao.java:24)     at
>   life.dao.ForumDao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6eb7cb5f.invoke()     at
>   net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
>     at life.dao.ForumDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8ecdd1fd.merge()
>     at life.dao.ForumDaoImpl.mergeDiscussion(ForumDaoImpl.java:29)  at
>   life.dao.ForumDaoImpl.saveNewPostForDiscussion(ForumDaoImpl.java:50)
>     at
>   life.dao.ForumDaoImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6d37da1f.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
>     at
>   life.dao.ForumDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$66b0b0bd.saveNewPostForDiscussion()
>     at
>   life.ui.layouts.ForumEditorLayout.replyToDiscussion(ForumEditorLayout.java:112)
>     at
>   life.ui.layouts.ForumEditorLayout$3.buttonClick(ForumEditorLayout.java:84)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:487)
>     ... 22 more Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:
>   could not insert: [life.domain_model.Post]    at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2327)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2834)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)   at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:62)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:415)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:341)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:258)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:877)   at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:859)    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:279)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)    at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:630)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:490)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867)   at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851)    at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:686)
>     ... 54 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Start position [1]
>   cannot exceed overall CLOB length [0]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy.invoke(ClobProxy.java:146)    at
>   $Proxy36.getSubString(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setClob(PreparedStatement.java:3553)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setClob(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setClob(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:187)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:60)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:89)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:282)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:277)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:85)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2166)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2143)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2321)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:56)
>     ... 85 more

and this is the Post entity  :

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private User owner;
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "editer_id")
    private User lastEditer;
    private Date creationDate;
    private Date lastEditionDate;
    @Lob
    private String content;
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "discussion_id")
    private Discussion discussion;

    public Post(){

    }
    public Post(User owner,String content){
        this.owner = owner;
        this.lastEditer = null;
        Date curent = new Date();
        this.creationDate = curent;
        this.lastEditionDate = curent;
        this.content = content;
        this.discussion = null;
    }


    //G&S
....
```

I get the error regardless of the String content length. I'm still using hibernate 3.6.0 and MySql 5.5 ( + spring ).  Can anyone tell me how to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue when trying to save empty strings to a field annotated with @Lob.  Found this bug slip: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5704

My project was implicitly including Hibernate core version 3.6.0, and once I updated the POM to explicitly include core version 3.6.10 it just started working as expected.

The ticket explains the problem very well.